# Access specific data from object by looping through

Tags: javascript, object

Here is my object:

```
var tools = {

    hammer: {

        name: "hammer",
        number: "23",
        owner;
        "John"

    },

    screwdriver: {

        name: "screwdriver",
        number: "72",
        owner: "Peter",

    },

    crowbar: {

        name: "crowbar",
        number: "6",
        owner: "Jack"

    }
};
```

This function gives me all the data back in the console log nicely:

My question is how can i get only the value for owner only from the object?

```
    Object.keys(tools).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, items[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `forEach` callback, Use `tools` instead of `items`. Your code in your question does not have anything assigned to `items` so it wont work as expected.

Access the `owner` property in `tools[key]` by doing `tools[key].owner`

You could remove `key,` from the `console.log` if you literally want just the owner name logged.

**Read up: [Property accessors | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**

```js
var tools = {

  hammer: {

    name: "hammer",
    number: "23",
    owner: "John"

  },

  screwdriver: {

    name: "screwdriver",
    number: "72",
    owner: "Peter",

  },

  crowbar: {

    name: "crowbar",
    number: "6",
    owner: "Jack"

  }
};

Object.keys(tools).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, tools[key].owner); // remove `key,` if you literally want just the owner name logged
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the owner name, do like this,

```
Object.keys(tools).forEach(function(key) {
 console.log(key, tools[key].owner);
});
```

Here `tools[key]` in the loop has the whole object, when you want a single property from it, just refer it with [**dot notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
var tools = {

  hammer: {

    name: "hammer",
    number: "23",
    owner: "John"

  },

  screwdriver: {

    name: "screwdriver",
    number: "72",
    owner: "Peter",

  },

  crowbar: {

    name: "crowbar",
    number: "6",
    owner: "Jack"

  }
};

Object.keys(tools).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, tools[key].owner);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the names in an array with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var tools = { hammer: { name: "hammer", number: "23", owner: "John" }, screwdriver: { name: "screwdriver", number: "72", owner: "Peter" }, crowbar: { name: "crowbar", number: "6", owner: "Jack" } },
    owners = Object.keys(tools).map(function(key) {
        return tools[key].owner;
    });

console.log(owners);
```

Comment: Thank to all of you, very much!